# The position of "for a X"

Tags: prepositions, word-order

I wrote:

> For example, if a variable must be set to #exData, a post-assignment is required because #exData **for a node** is initially empty and will be filled after visiting all the child nodes.

*#exData* is defined for each node separately and it is initially empty for that node. I am not sure about the position of "for a node". Did I use it correctly?

Also I don't know if before *because* I need comma or not.

Comment: How about "because **a node's** exData property" instead of **for a node**?  Also, what is doing the *visiting*?

Comment: @TRomano yes, **a node's exData** is much better. Please also say your opinion about my confusions beside your suggestions. It may be needed for other sentences. Now, I don't know if "#exData for a node" is totally wrong or not.

Comment: @TRomano there is a function which is called recursively with every node. then by *visiting* I mean calling the function on a node.

Comment: How about "...is initially empty and is filled after all the child nodes have been visited".  Is the filling a one-time occurrence that happens after the final child node has been visited?

Comment: *exData for a node* is not wrong but unclear. The preposition **for** isn't as clear as the possessive "a node's..."

Comment: @TRomano yes, your suggestion is better as always. the filling is Not a one-time occurrence. the data returned by each call on a child node is added to the exData in a loop.

Comment: A node's #exData property, initially null (or empty), is updated as each of its child nodes is processed in turn.

Comment: My first thought: Why not *of a node* (rather than *for a node*)?, which is along the same lines as TRomano's comments.

Comment: @DamkerngT. it even could be *for each node*, in fact I have an emphasis on both facts that it is *of a node* and is initially empty *for that node*!

Comment: @TRomano or *... is initially empty and will be **available** after all the child nodes have been visited*, rather saying when and how it is filled.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a minimalist answer to your specific questions.

> "For example, if a variable must be set to #exData, a post-assignment is required because #exData **for a node** is initially empty and will be filled after visiting all the child nodes."
>
> *#exData* is defined for each node separately and it is initially empty for that node. I am not sure about the position of "for a node". Did I use it correctly?

The position is fine.  It could be clearer to write "for a **particular** node".

> Also I don't know if before *because* I need comma or not.

Optional.  A good way to decide is to read the sentence out loud, and see whether you think pausing at that spot makes it easier or harder for the listener to follow what you're saying.  If you desire a pause, use a comma.  If you feel a pause there breaks up the flow too much, omit the comma.

Sorry, one other comment: it might be helpful to insert *only* as follows: "... and will **only** be filled after visiting all the child nodes."

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are trying to express is

1) #exData is a property of a node object
2) #exData's value is initially *empty* (possibly nil?)
3) #exData's value is set during some form of a callback

in this case

> for a node

is understandable and correct.  What possibly makes your description confusing is

> if a *variable* must be set to #exData...

which maybe should read

> if a *value* must be set *for* #exData...

since from your description #exData is the variable (object property) which is assigned a value, not that a variable is assigned the value "#exData".  You could then use

> #exData's *value* is initially empty...

Comment: Thank you, but *the variable* is correct. It is another variable which is set to the value of the #exData variable. (We have assignment of a variable to another variable) but when the variable on the right is empty the assignment is not meaningful.